# Javascript scope: passing a variable from an outer function to an inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, variables, scope

I define the variable "a" in the outerFunction. I want to use it in my innerFunction. How come this doesn't work, and what is the best way to pass data between nested functions?

```
var outerFunction = function () {
   var a = 5;
   innerFunction();
}


var innerFunction = function () {
   alert(a);
}

outerFunction();
```

Comment: Your "inner" function is not *in* anything :P

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: eeeeeeew. A 16k rep user promoting w3schools. Shame on you ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa In this case, I think the OP has a lot of elementary reading to catch up on.

Comment: That's why I would have directed OP to MDN.

Comment: I like MDN, too, but [it's certainly not beginner-level reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: @Blazemonger: Yet, there are better introductions at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript

Comment: w3schools == [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). If you don't know, now you know.

Comment: @Bergi Those are terrible beginner-level links, and not one of them would directly help OP with this problem. I stand by my choice of links. I've read w3fools.com before and found its arguments specious. MDN is only suitable as a reference, not a teaching tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add parameter to inner function and pass value to it from outer function.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wCFm/)**

```
var outerFunction = function () {
   var a = 5;
   innerFunction(a);
}


var innerFunction = function (a) {
   alert(a);
}

outerFunction();
```

Answer (score 4):

`innerFunction`  is not the inner function of `outeFunction` you are just calling it from `outerFunction` . 
Innerfunction should be defined like below.

```
var outerFunction = function () {
   var a = 5;
   var innerFunction = function () {
    alert(a);
   }
   innerFunction();
}
```

Comment: I'm worried if I start defining functions within functions, my script is quickly going to lose any modularity and just be a chain of one function. Is there a more modular way to do this?

Comment: You should create function on same level. but pass parameter in called function as already suggested in other answers. above I showed how to create inner function.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript functions are bound to their context. It means that variable defined inside `outerFunction` exists only there and not in global context. But for function `innerFunction` this scope is not available. So you can't access it. If you need it you should pass it as an argument to `innerFunction` explictly.

Answer (score 1):

Just actually nest them:

```
var outerFunction = function () {

    var innerFunction = function () {
        alert(a);
    }

    var a = 5;
    innerFunction();
}

outerFunction();
```

Now `innerFunction`'s scope (to which the `alert` has acess) is inside the scope of the `outerFunction` where `a` is declared.

Comment: While this works, please don't do this, scope-sharing can be difficult to debug, use parameters instead.

Comment: @DustyJ: Huh? What's wrong with closures? Also, nesting them is the only way to get an "inner" and an "outer" function.

Answer (score 0):

var defines a local scope for a variable. If you don't intend to pass variables, then do this,

```
var outerFunction = function () {
   a = 5;
   innerFunction();
}


var innerFunction = function () {
   alert(a);
}

outerFunction();
```

But the clean approach would be to pass in the variable

```
innerFunction(a)
```

Comment: Polluting the global scope is not a solution.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote here. I have mentioned, that if you dont intend to pass in the variables. I thought it would be a good learning as well for the person, and knowing the importance of var

Comment: You forgot to mention it is really bad to do.

Comment: accepted you say? You know only one answer can be accepted on a question right and the best should be chosen?

Comment: Downvoted, usage of global scope is a worst-case practice, and shouldn't ever be used.